# What is this species of asphodel from Morocco?

Tags: species-identification, botany

It grew about 2 metres high. Photographed in spring. It has 6 tepals and 6 stamens. [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to be *Asphodelus aestivus*, but there is similarity with *Asphodelus ramosus*, both of which have strap like leaves and highly branched stems. They have some overlapping ranges as well in southern Mediterranean/north Africa.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asphodelus_aestivus

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asphodelus#Systematics